# Como instalar o php-5 no ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, instalador, php-5

Sou usuário novo no *Ubuntu*, e não estou conseguindo instalar o *PHP-5* via apt-get, já que a versão estável é a *PHP-7*, recebo um erro dizendo que nenhum pacote foi encontrado.
*Tentei utilizar os seguintes comandos*

```
sudo apt-get install php
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

Mas sem sucesso em nenhum.

Alguém sabe como faço para instalar?

Comment: Você está recebendo algum erro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depois de o PHP ter tornado a versão `7` do PHP estável, parece que o PPA do PHP mudou e é necessário atualizá-la.

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
  sudo apt-get update
```

Outra coisa importante é que agora é necessário especificar qual versão do PHP você vai instalar (se é 5.5, 5.6 ou 7.0).

Veja:

```
 sudo apt-get install php5.6 php5.6-common php5.6-mcrypt
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, vou testar assim que puder.