# Como atualizar a versão do PHP no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Fui tentar instalar uma dependência e ele pediu uma versão maior do PHP.

```
Problem 1
```

> - illuminate/support v5.3.4 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - illuminate/support v5.3.16 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - illuminate/support v5.3.0 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - elibyy/tcpdf-laravel 5.3.0 requires illuminate/support 5.3.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.4].
> - Installation request for elibyy/tcpdf-laravel 5.3.* -> satisfiable by elibyy/tcpdf-laravel[5.3.0].

Existe uma forma de atualizar a versão do php no `composer.json`?

Comment: Você tem que instalar a versão do PHP no seu Sistema Operacional do Computador, via `composer.json` não dá, ele é para o gerenciador de pacote. Qual é o sistema operacional?

Comment: Não adianta trocar a versão requisitada do php no composer pq daí não vai funcionar o laravel, tem que atualizar o PHP mesmo.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Uso Windows 7

Comment: @Denali tem que instalar o php maior ou igual 5.6.4, no servidor que esteja usando. Eu acabei esquecendo qual é o servidor que está usando? Apache ou IIS ?

Comment: Você usa Wamp, Xampp ou algum outro servidor local?

Answer (score 1):

> Existe uma forma de atualizar a versão do php no `composer.json`?

Não existe como "atualizar o PHP" através do Composer. O que pode ser feito é alterar a versão requerida para o funcionamento da aplicação.

Porém, no seu caso, você realmente precisa atualizar o PHP no seu sistema operacional, já que o requerimento padrão do *Laravel 5.3* requer o `PHP 5.6.4 >=`, e você está usando a versão `5.5.9`.

Sendo assim, instale a versão do PHP requirida, que o problema será resolvido.

Talvez essa pergunta ajude:

[Como instalar o php-5 no ubuntu?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155406/como-instalar-o-php-5-no-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Para aqueles que precisarem atualizar para o php 7.4 (último atualmente) com ubuntu 18.04 e Laravel:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.4-fpm
sudo apt install php7.4-common php7.4-mysql php7.4-xml php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-curl php7.4-gd php7.4-imagick php7.4-cli php7.4-dev php7.4-imap php7.4-mbstring php7.4-opcache php7.4-soap php7.4-zip php7.4-intl -y
```

Depois de atualizado o PHP vá no arquivo `package.json` que fica na raiz da aplicação e mude a versão do php:

```
...
"platform": {
    "php": "7.4"
}
...
```